# Which One is faster? Spark SQL with Where clause or Use of Filter in Dataframe after Spark SQL

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Which One is faster? Spark SQL with Where clause or Use of Filter in Dataframe after Spark SQL?

Like Select col1, col2 from tab 1 where col1=val;

Or

dataframe df=sqlContext.sql(Select col1, col2 from tab 1);

df.filter("Col1=Val");

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `explain` method to see the physical plan is a good way to determine performance.

For example, the Zeppelin Tutorial notebook.

```
sqlContext.sql("select age, job from bank").filter("age = 30").explain
```

And

```
sqlContext.sql("select age, job from bank where age = 30").explain
```

Has exactly the same physical plan.

```
== Physical Plan ==
Project [age#5,job#6]
+- Filter (age#5 = 30)
   +- Scan ExistingRDD[age#5,job#6,marital#7,education#8,balance#9]
```

So the performance shall be the same.

Through I think `select age, job from bank where age = 30` is more readable in this case.